# change href via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I can't change the href in this script. But innerHTML works. What is wrong?

```
   <script>
        FB.init({
            appId: 1234, 
            cookie: true,
            status: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                document.getElementById('test').href = 'http://www.example.com/auth/login';
                // document.getElementById('index-facebook-login-button').innerHTML = '<a class="index-facebook-login-button" href="http://www.example.com/auth/login" target="_self"></a>';

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                document.getElementById('test').href += 'http://www.example.com/connectfacebook';
                //this works!!!                    
                //document.getElementById('index-facebook-login-button').innerHTML = '<a class="index-facebook-login-button" href="http://www.example.com/connectfacebook" target="_self"></a>';

            } else {
                document.getElementById('test').href += 'http://www.example.com/connectfacebook';
                //this works!!!                    
               // document.getElementById('index-facebook-login-button').innerHTML = '<a class="index-facebook-login-button" href="http://www.example.com/connectfacebook" target="_self"></a>';
            }

        });
    </script>

<div id="index-facebook-login-text" onLoad="FB.getLoginStatus();">
some text here
    <div id="index-facebook-login-button" style="margin-left: 25px;">
            <a id="test" class="index-facebook-login-button" href="" target="_self"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe at the moment you are trying to access the element, it does not exist or does not have that ID? Set a breakpoint, check the DOM structure... the usual debugging procedure.

Comment: Why `href +=` in the 2nd and 3rd case? Makes little sense (unless the current URL would be something that already has an empty parameter attached.)

Answer (score -1):

The attributes of the Element object in Javascript's DOM API are not the same as the attributes of the actual element in the DOM. This object is just an interface to the DOM. You want to use the setAttribute() method:

```
document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com')
```

h̶t̶t̶p̶:̶/̶/̶w̶w̶w̶.̶w̶3̶s̶c̶h̶o̶o̶l̶s̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶j̶s̶r̶e̶f̶/̶m̶e̶t̶_̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶_̶s̶e̶t̶a̶t̶t̶r̶i̶b̶u̶t̶e̶.̶a̶s̶p̶  ([don't use W3school](http://w3fools.com/))
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute

Comment: *"The attributes of the Element object in Javascript's DOM API are not the same as the attributes of the actual element in the DOM."* That's a bit confusing IMO. Yes, `href` is not the same as `getAttribute('href')`, but for the purpose of setting it, it does not really matter in this case. JavaScript's DOM API still follows the official DOM API and its HTML DOM extension.